# asp.net web application adfs authentication of client intranet in azure cloud without azure AD

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, azure-web-app-service, adfs

I know the title looks a bit odd. I am asked to create a simple web application that will be hosted in azure cloud. The client has an on-premises adfs and wants the application to handle the sso from their organization. They do not want to use azure AD and are against it. Can you guys let me know if it's possible? I have seen a lot of samples with Owin and Oauth authentication but they all point to Azure AD with adfs authentication. Any samples would be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - and there are some samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-scenarios-for-developers).

**Update**

No - there are no Microsoft samples because Microsoft does not have a client side SAML stack.

Refer [I need a SAML stack — now!](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) for some client side ideas - most have samples in the documentation.

Comment: the client specifically wants to implement SAML 2.0 Service provider initiated SSO in web forms application. Are there any samples for that?